# GetTextExtentPoint32W returns different values in different computers

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to adjust button width depending on the current language that is set in comboBox. For some language like spanish some of the texts are just too long to be fitted into PUSHBUTTON. All controls are in .rc file. To calculate PUSHBUTTON width I'm using RECT (rect.right - rect.left) and to calculate text widht I'm using GetTextExtentPoint32W but unfortunately this method is giving me different values  depending in what PC is running. In my laptop where resolution is set to 1920x1080 and scalling100% (recommended is 125%) text width is around 25% bigger than in PC with the same configuration

Comment: Why does it matter? Surely the whole point is to dynamically size the control, you shouldn't care what size it ends up.

Comment: But after getting values from GetTextExtentPoint32W I'm using it to resize control by using MoveWindow method and before that I'm checking if width of text is actually bigger than width of control so in one PC gonna be true and works fine but in another it's false and control will not resize. Strange thing is that width of control is the same on both PCs

Comment: Is your application manifested to be DPI aware?

Comment: No it's not. I didn't make any changes in manifest

Comment: What's the `PUSHBUTTON` width on your laptop? What's the condition after enabling DPI Awareness?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the Device Context which may be different across PCs.
Also, you need to be DPI-Aware (since your scalling is not 100%) and GDI isn't.

Suggestion: move to Direct2D.

Comment: Moving to Direct2D is not possible. Application is quite big and rely only on win32

Comment: Direct2D *is* Win32.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that